# Proving an equation $\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{x=0}^{2} [(f'(x)e^{6x}\Delta x] = \int_{0}^{2} e^{14x}dx $

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, provability

Continuing from this forum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2257417/is-fx-dx-fx-fx-dx-a-valid-equation), suppose that $f(x)=\dfrac{e^{8x}}{8}$ and $f'(x) = e^{8x}$. I was told that : $\displaystyle\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\sum_{x=0}^{2} [(f'(x)e^{6x}\Delta x]  = \int_{0}^{2} e^{14x}dx $

How can this be proven ?

Note: I don't quite understand whether some are supposed to be $dx$ or $\Delta x$. I'm not able to confirm it right now but I think it is supposed to be which ever make sense and can get you to prove that it is equal to  $\int_{0}^{2} e^{14x}dx $. I do need recommendation regarding this. I will edit the question accordingly if it is proven be to one or the other.

Comment: I would change the $dx$ to $\Delta x$ in the sum. $dx$ is usually used for $\Delta x$ in the limit that $\Delta x $ approaches $0$. It doesn't mean much of anything to limit $dx$ to $0$.

Comment: For the equality, see the definition of Riemann Sums.

Comment: I'm quite certain that something is wrong.  With two $\Delta x$ in the sum, the limit is $0$.

Comment: How about now? Some I changed to $dx$

Comment: The sum is fundamentally flawed. According to the way it is written, there are only 3 terms in it, and when you take the limit you've written, all 3 terms go to 0, so it certainly won't have the limit on the right side of the $=$. Check the definition of a Riemann sum more closely.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Is this after I edited or before? How about now with the $dx$ in place.

Comment: I edited again. Thx

Comment: This has serious problems. You need to understand properly about a Riemann sum. Also I don't get what is $dx$ doing in a Riemann sum. Note that $dx$ in the notation for integral is just a part of notation and does not serve any purpose other than helping us to remember the rule of substitution in integration.

Comment: The linked problem is equally flawed and may be the source of the ongoing confusion.

Comment: Please edit your question properly so that it makes sense otherwise it may get more close votes.

Comment: $dx$ in the limits of integration makes no sense.

Comment: Changed it. How about now?